# Strange interaction between WinXP setting and internet access?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, wired-networking

This is strange.  My Mac was broken, so I tried to use my sister's XP machine.  I also had used it about six months ago, cleaned up a lot of spyware, and installed a lot of updates, and it worked fine afterward for me in my own admin-enabled account.

This time, Chrome told me there was no internet connection.  Last time, it was on WiFi, but this time it appeared to have no WiFi board, and the network diagnostics "confirmed" that the wired connection wasn't communicating.

Logged on to her grandson's account (no password,but a limited account) and Chrome had no problem getting to the websites I was after.

Went back to my account, verified Chrome still said no internet.  Pulled up a DOS Window, verified I could ping Google's DNS server by IP address, and my former employer by domain name.  The employer is in Indiana and we're in Oklahoma.  Did a traceroute to a server in Germany, fifteen hops.  Noticed to my surprise that the pings were only taking an average of **three** milliseconds!

Thought maybe the Chrome shortcut was pointing to a bad copy, so I checked both shortcuts and they were the same.  But the "advanced" properties were interesting:
[image: advanced shortcut properties]
With different credentials OFF, Chrome said that there was no internet connection.  With it ON, launching gave this:
[image: “Run As” properties]
Click OK with these settings, and Chrome did not launch at all.  Turn off the protection, and it launches and appears to work normally.

Default settings on XP in the properties of **one** program's shortcut blocked internet access to that program **and** to Window's diagnostic wizard but did not block it for DOS commands.

Any explanation?

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of that mystery setting and where it is found? Also, Indiana to Germany would be a minimum of 23 ms at the speed of light – in practice around 100 ms usually. No matter what, 3 ms sounds shady.

Comment: The pings were three.  The traceroute was also surprisingly fast, but the nodes along the way had believable host names.  I left out a detail (oops): will edit question to fix.

Comment: Oklahoma to Germany, actually.  The former employer is in Indiana, where 3ms is good for radio (great circle distance), but suspicious for a multi-hop internet pathway.  Malware could presumably fake a ping, but hard to believe it could fake a traceroute AND make it seem faster than normal.

Comment: Also, the Access control panel did not put any restrictions on Chrome.  There were no other browser shortcuts on the Desktop, and I did not go looking for them.

Comment: If you're that worried about it since you removed a bunch of software, do an HD format and wipe it entirely with fresh copy of XP. If you do not trust the laptop or assume it's infected.... then DON'T USE IT!! Sounds like a pretty simple problem to fix actually. You're chasing ghosts man, so good luck with that all the way from the Thunder to the Pacers, or from the Sooner's to the Hoosier's!!

Comment: It's not a laptop,it's not mine, and I doubt my sister has any clue where to find her XP installation disk.  And the only things I removed were malware, and it did not have this odd problem afterward.  I'm not worried, just extremely curious about something so weird.